# Angular: Form validation and custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two inputs and I need to validate each fields with the following restriction: The *Value B* must always be minor than *Value A* otherwise show an error message. This is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5fjC54481cgesy4Bbvp?p=preview).

I know I need to create a directive but I don't know even how to start.

*HTML*

```
<form name="exampleForm">
    <label>Value A</label>
    <input type="number" name="valueA" data-ng-model="valueA" required="required"/>
    <div ng-messages="exampleForm.valueA.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
    <p>
    <label>Value B</label>
    <input type="number" name="valueB" data-ng-model="valueB" required="required"/>
    <div ng-messages="exampleForm.valueB.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [Have a look at the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation), there's an example of custom validation which will get you on tracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" name="valueB" data-ng-model="valueB" max="{{ valueA - 1 }}" required="required"/>
  <div ng-messages="exampleForm.valueB.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="max">This field is too large</div>
  </div>
```